# Error in Jupyter Notebook: What could be the reason?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Recently I updated R n Jupyter Lab with homebrew.
Today, I am surprised that R failed to run on ipython notebook with error below:

```
Error Starting Kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.3/lib/R/bin/R': '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.3/lib/R/bin/R'
```

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting part of the error is.

```sh
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.3/lib/R/bin/R': '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.3/lib/R/bin/R'
```

I guess you Jupyter kernel is referencing the old installation of R that you have updated.
The first thing to do is to check what is defined in your R kernel.

### Check kernel

```sh
# list all kernel
jupyter kernelspec list

#Available kernels:
#  ir           /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
# ...
```

You should have an `ir` kernel.
Check the content of the kernel definition, for example:

```
$ cat /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir/kernel.json 

# {"argv": ["R", "--slave", "-e", "IRkernel::main()", "--args", "{connection_file}"],
# "display_name":"R",
# "language":"R"
# }
```

If the command in `argv` is incorrect you can remove an reinstall the kernel.

## Remove and reinstall the kernel

See the [IRkernel installation documentation](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) for more information.

```sh
$ jupyter kernelspec remove ir
$ R
# Install IRkernel
> install.packages('IRkernel')
# Or update it if already installed
> update.packages('IRkernel')
# Install the kernel
> IRkernel::installspec()
# Or alternatively if you want to install it system-wide
> IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

Comment: Here is the result ~~ cat: /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir/kernel.json: No such file or directorycat /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir/kernel.json after running cat /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir/kernel.json.

Comment: @OngK.S You have to check the content of `kernel.json` with your own path, the path returned by the command `jupyter kernelspec list`, `/opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/ir/kernel.json` is an example.

Comment: tq for your advice. I removed kernel and reinstall IRkernel from rStudio. However, I have this message and issue remain: * removing ‘/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/uuid’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘uuid’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘uuid’ is not available for package ‘IRkernel’
* removing ‘/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/IRkernel’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘IRkernel’ had non-zero exit status.

Comment: @OngK.S It's another problem now related to the installation of `IRkernel`.  You may try to update your packages in R... Sorry but it turns to be a complicated issue.

Comment: @Ramain, I managed to solve it by installing dependencies for irkernel. install irkernel after all dependencies downloaded. Succeed. TQ anyway.

Comment: @OngK.S Cool, I've modified my answer to add a step to install it. I think this procedure could be useful for others. Would you mind accept it, since it has helped you solving your issue?

Comment: sure. This is where we share knowledge collectively.